# Ajax calls no working with Facebook Canvas app

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, canvas

I'm trying to get my website accessible via a FB Canvas. It is working but when I tried to use ajax to call the log on script nothing happened. So I tested the only other ajax call on my site from within the canvas and that did nothing too. Is there something else I need to do to make an ajax call?

I have a page Canvas.php which contains the code FB gives for logging in a user but I also need to log them onto my site:

```
function onLogin(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
      var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
      welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '. Welcome to MyScrabbleApp on FB!';

       // use an ajax call to  log_on_or_off.php ??

          $.ajax(
       {
         url: 'log_on_or_off.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {action:'canvas', username:data.name, fb_id:data.id}

         }
     );

 alert("You called log on for " + data.name + " with fb_id " + data.id);


});
```

}
}

[I also tried a different approach using the FacebookCanvasLoginHelper but it wasn't very helpful :-( ]

Comment: ajax calls do work without a problem. you need to start debugging. "nothing happens" is not a sufficient error description.

Comment: Fair point. That's why I tried the other ajax call which works on the site but not 'under canvas'. I'm not experienced in js but I guess I'll just have to put in lots of output statements.

Comment: that, and you need to use the browser dev tools for debugging

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It just seems that the script gets stuck at the ajax call. What browser dev tools could I use to find out what's happening? All I use is CTRL-U!

Comment: press f12 in chrome. i guess there is some error im your php file then.

Comment: Hmm, that wouldn't explain why another script which uses an ajax call works outside the canvas but not inside. There must be something else I need to do/set/include. It just seems the ajax call crashes and I can't see where or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a remote version of jQuery so the ajax request was not over HTTPS. Easily fixed once problem was identified. Thanks to luschn for suggesting debugging using F12 in Chrome.